# Error connection to phpmyadmin with servername

Tags: php, mysql, linux, server, phpmyadmin

So I think the error is something from the phpmyadmin configuration but i dno'tknow what exactly
If i try to connect to my database with php it work if i use localhost on the serverdbname.
But if i the variable serverdbname i put the webname.com it doesn't work but also it doesn't give any error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A04L.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9jDb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnG7K.png)

Comment: If localhost works - why do you want to change it? It would be only sane (if one thinks of having database and web frontend on the same server as sane - I wouldn't necessarily) to be able to reach the DB only on the loopback interface and not via a public IP.

Comment: Don’t confuse your website’s DNS name with other DNS addresses. Your website, for instance, is probably publicly accessible, but in an ideal world your database is **not**.

Answer (score 0):

If your address "webname.com" is allowed to take remote connection you can put it as host name. So First you need to make it available in remote connection. Then you can use the dns name  or it's ip address as host name.